# running selenium tests via jmeter on blazemeter remotely

Tags: selenium, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

We have a jmeter test that launches selenium scripts using the [chrome driver config plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=ChromeDriverConfig)  which runs with the [Web Driver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=WebDriverSampler), with which we are uploading our own chrome driver. The driver wont be allowed to work though, we keep getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /tmp/artifacts/chromedriver
```

we need a way to chmod +x the driver or something similar. is there a way to do this?

Blazemeter support said

> JMeter's Webdriver plugin has been deprecated and is not supported on BlazeMeter

but I don't see anything deprecating the webdriver plugin from jmeter The repo and main website seem updated and active.

https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver

https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=WebDriverSampler

TL/DR: Can we run a selenium test from within a jmeter test using a `<com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler` on blazemeter? what are the steps to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit this exact issue, this is probably too late for you but I thought it would be useful to answer for someone else in the future.

According to [this Blazemeter Post](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) titled:
"Using Selenium with JMeter's WebDriver Sampler"

> "To launch the WebDriver test in the cloud with more concurrent users on BlazeMeter, use Firefox, which is the only currently supported browser for use with WebDriver. Create a new test and upload your JMX file to run it."

So in summary, only firefox is supported, not chrome within Blazemeter.

Comment: They could put it in a blog post, but not the damn error message. OK.

Comment: Thanks though great answer!

Answer (score 1):

I work on a lot of BlazeMeter's documentation and can verify the previous answer -- the Webdriver plugin for JMeter is no longer supported on BlazeMeter.

That's not to say you can't get it to work -- you might -- but it's not supported (i.e. the support team can't assist with any problems that arise with it).

Some added context: We know folks in the plugin development community, which is how we learned the plugin is "deprecated" in the sense that there's not much in the way of future development for it going forward.  You're right though - it's not documented anywhere, unfortunately.  I can't speak to why that is on the plugin side, but that's why it is no longer supported on the BlazeMeter side.

The other reason it's no longer supported is that we recently introduced a new feature to replace it, our "GUI Functional Test" feature in BlazeMeter, which lets you run Selenium tests either through our BlazeMeter UI or from your own IDE, then watch a recording of what happened in the browser afterward.  We have a set of guides covering the topic, starting here:
https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000700158

We also introduced a means to run a Selenium test alongside a JMeter test, via what we call our End User Experience Monitoring feature, detailed here:
https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000262118

(That blog post referenced above is a very old one that unfortunately no longer applies today.  I regrettably don't work on the blog side of the house, so I don't have the authority to update that one myself.)

Lastly, please let me know if there's any pain points in our docs that we can fix. I've been putting a lot of work into improving and expanding our existing documentation, so feedback is always welcome.