# Jmeter script with Webdriver Sampler unable to find Chromedriver on Blazemeter

Tags: jmeter, webdriver, blazemeter

I do have a load testing script built using jmeter and works fine on local machine as I know where is my chrome driver. But when I upload same script on Blazemeter it does not work because not sure where chromedriver is.

Can someone tell me how to find chromedrive path on blazemeter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question should rather go to [BlazeMeter support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket) because we don't know anything about their infrastructure hence cannot provide the comprehensive answer.

I think they use [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Index/) tool under the hood so you can add [Selenium Executor](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Selenium/) to your existing test, however it has different syntax than the WebDriver Sampler.

It might also be possible to upload **linux64** version of chromedriver along with your test plan however I don't think BlazeMeter allows uploading and executing random binaries from security perspective (at least I wouldn't allow it)

---

In case they do - don't forget to:

1. Make `chromedriver` executable somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with the code

   ```
   "chmod +x chromedriver".execute()
   ```
2. Tick `Headless` box in ChromeDriver Config
3. Use just `chromedriver` as the executable path.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. I have found here that Blazemeter no longer supports Webdriver plugin. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57699928/running-selenium-tests-via-jmeter-on-blazemeter-remotely

Still I would go and ask to Blazemeter support as you suggested.

Comment: It's 4 years old, situation could change since then, see my update under the horizontal line, it seem to work with the latest chromedriver for free account.

Comment: Sure. Let me try that.